# Creating a real time website using PHP

Tags: php, python, node.js, real-time

I'm currently creating a website using PHP and the Kohana framework.  I want to site to be able to use real time (or near real time) data (e.g. for chat and real time feeds).  I need it to be able to scale to thousands of concurrent users.  I've done a lot of reading and still have no idea what the best method is for this.

Does anyone have any experience with StreamHub?  Is it possible to use this with PHP?

Am I digging myself into a hole here and need to switch languages?  I've looked at node js and nowjs, but I'm weary about coding a while site in Express (I wonder about security holes, code maintainability, lack of a good ORM).  I've read about Twisted Python, but have no idea what web framework would work well on top of that, and I'd prefer not to use Nevow - maybe Django can be used well with Twisted Python?  I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction, so I don't go too far in PHP and realize I can't get the near real-time results that I need.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Choice of language isn't the issue here.

Comment: @Brad choice of language isn't the issue, choice of WebServer is and languages seem to be tied to servers.

Answer (score 2):

> I've looked at node js and nowjs, but
>   I'm weary about coding a while site in
>   Express (I wonder about security
>   holes, code maintainability, lack of a
>   good ORM).

I can personally vouch for code maintainability if you can do JavaScript. I personally find JavaScript more maintainable then PHP but that's probably due to lack of PHP experience.

ORM is not an issue as node.js favours document based databases. Document based databases and JSON go hand in hand, I find couch db and it's map/reduce system easy to use and it feels natural with json.

In terms of security holes, yes a node.js server is young and there may be holes. These are un avoidable. There are currently no known exploits and I would say it's not much more vulnerable 
then IIS/apache/nginx until someone points a big flaw.

> I want to site to be able to use real
>   time (or near real time) data (e.g.
>   for chat and real time feeds). I need
>   it to be able to scale to thousands of
>   concurrent users.

Scalability like that requires non-blocking IO. This requires a non-blocking IO server likes nginx or node.js (Yes blocking IO could work but you need *so* much more hardware).

Personally I would advice using node.js over PHP as it's easier to write non blocking IO in node. You can do it in PHP but you have to make all the right design and architecture decisions. I doubt there are any truly async non-blocking PHP frameworks.

Python's twisted / Ruby's EventMachine together with nginx, can work but I have no expertise with those. At least with node you can't accidentally call a blocking library or make use of the native blocking libraries since JavaScript has no native IO.

Comment: Thanks Raynos.  I have node js and express installed and I'm playing around with them now.  I am liking the structure so far, but I'm very pro MVC.  I've been looking at MongoDB and Mongoose to to be able to create actual models.  On the MVC subject, do you know of any good code samples that implement MVC for express?

Comment: @smpappas there is a big difference between database models and server models. If you want MVC use [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and express. I havn't seen any solid tutorials, I plan to write one. There's some code on github you can read. There is also [geddy](http://www.geddyjs.org). Feel free to read any of the good resources around like howtonode & [node tuts](http://nodetuts.com/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  As I'm still new to node, I'm looking into Express and Backbone, various DB options.  The model part I'm not as concerned with, I know that can be done to my liking.  Do you know of any code samples or application shells that implement the View-Controller interaction (possibly with express and backbone or other)?  I'm just trying to avoid putting any real logic in the views - my way of thinking is still PHP-ish, so I'm trying to bridge the gap.  Good example code has always been the best way of learning for me.  Thanks again for all the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not the language you should be using for real-time updates of a website.  PHP scripts load first before HTML (and HTML calls javascript files), so PHP cannot update your page for you.  However, when used with AJAX (eg. using a jQuery function to call a PHP file to update your page in real-time), you can use PHP in this fashion.

Using jQuery and AJAX (all javascript), you can do quite a bit in terms of updating a page without reloading it.  I've seen sites such as [this one](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBwQFjAB&url=http://plugins.jquery.com/project/chat&rct=j&q=jquery%20chat&ei=qfumTZf0CYOM0QGMhdH5CA&usg=AFQjCNFS8kgU-ELvjakhp4w5CffPQ1Z-Fg&sig2=e4mUscb8EQUSHLqC7FcJyg&cad=rja) that demonstrate how to make a chat using jQuery.

Comment: I believe that things like facebook chat actually update the chat window without using AJAX but by using Comet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Comment: @AdamPointer comet is a variant of ajax.

Comment: That's interesting.  Thanks for the read!  I stand corrected on that front. My main point, however, is just that PHP is not what should be used for what smpappas is asking about.

Comment: @Raynos - Indeed it is, unfortunatly cannot edit my comment now, but for all you pedants out there -  "update the chat window without using conventional AJAX techniques"

Comment: Link is dead now